# sql If statement or case

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I think I may be missing the obvious here but im trying to create a sql query to pull data out in a particular way but cant work it out.

I have a table which is made up with the following columns:

```
Name, StageDate, Stage
```

I want to create in sql an output something like this:

```
Name, Stage, Stage1Date, Stage2Date, Stage3Date

Person1, 1, 01/01/2015, NULL, NULL

Person1, 2, 01/01/2015, 02/01/2015, NULL

Person1, 3, 01/01/2015, 02/01/2015, 03/01/2015
```

My query is currently as follows:

```
select Name
        , Stage
        , Case when Stage = 1 then StageDate end as Stage1Date
        , Case when Stage = 2 then StageDate end as Stage2Date
        , Case when Stage = 3 then StageDate end as Stage3Date
From Details
```

Data export for the above query currently looks like this:

```
Name, Stage, Stage1Date, Stage2Date, Stage3Date

Person1, 1, 01/01/2015, NULL, NULL

Person1, 2, NULL, 02/01/2015, NULL

Person1, 3, NULL, NULL, 03/01/2015
```

Comment: I think comma (,) after Name in your select is missing

Comment: How does the table data look? What's wrong with the result of your current query?

Comment: to me all the query is wrong:) you can use where stage=(case when....)

Comment: Case when Stage <= 1/2/3...

Comment: Ive just edited the original post to show the result of my current query

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: instead of Stage = 1 use Stage <= 1 and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Stages TABLE (
      Name varchar(20), 
      Stage int, 
      StageDate datetime);

INSERT INTO @Stages (Name, Stage, StageDate)
VALUES
    ('Player 1', 1, '2015-04-01'),
    ('Player 1', 2, '2015-05-01'),
    ('Player 1', 3, '2015-06-01'),
    ('Player 2', 1, '2015-04-01'),
    ('Player 2', 2, '2015-05-01');

SELECT NAME, Stage, 
        CASE WHEN Stage >=1 THEN (SELECT s2.StageDate FROM @Stages s2 Where s2.Name = s1.Name and s2.Stage =1)  Else NULL END As Stage1Date,
        CASE WHEN Stage >=2 THEN (SELECT s2.StageDate FROM @Stages s2 Where s2.Name = s1.Name and s2.Stage =2)  Else NULL END As Stage2Date,
        CASE WHEN Stage >=3 THEN (SELECT s2.StageDate FROM @Stages s2 Where s2.Name = s1.Name and s2.Stage =3)  Else NULL END As Stage3Date
 FROM @Stages s1
```

- [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/406b6/4)

Comment: Yes that one is exactly what I needed, brilliant I did try a select in my case statement originally but just got errors as wasn't sure of the syntax

Comment: Just take care to add the right UNIQUE indices to avoid each subquery to return more than one row.

Comment: No worries. I'm sure that there may be a superior way of doing it using PIVOT or other stuff, but i haven't much experience using it myself. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Name
        , Stage
        , StageDate as Stage1Date
        , Case when (Stage = 2 OR Stage = 3) then StageDate else null end as Stage2Date
        , Case when Stage = 3 then StageDate else null end as Stage3Date
From Details
```

Comment: @user3691566 All the displayed stagedates on the same row will be the same instead of each stage date as described in your sample output. So I doubt this is the right answer. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/406b6/2).

Comment: Ah yes ive just noticed that :(

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could come up with for now is using `UNIONS`, as an alternatives to other answers using subqueries:

```
SELECT Name, 
       stage, 
       stagedate AS Stage1Date, 
       NULL      AS Stage2Date, 
       NULL      AS Stage3Date 
FROM   details 
WHERE  stage = 1 
UNION 
SELECT d1.Name, 
       d1.stage, 
       d1.stagedate AS Stage1Date, 
       d2.stagedate AS Stage2Date, 
       NULL         AS Stage3Date 
FROM   details d1 
       INNER JOIN details d2 ON d1.NAME = d2.NAME 
                  AND d1.stage = 1 AND d2.stage = 2 
UNION 
SELECT d1.Name, 
       d1.stage, 
       d1.stagedate AS Stage1Date, 
       d2.stagedate AS Stage2Date, 
       d3.stagedate AS Stage3Date 
FROM   details d1 
       INNER JOIN details d2 ON d1.NAME = d2.NAME 
                  AND d1.stage = 1 AND d2.stage = 2 
       INNER JOIN details d3 ON d1.NAME = d3.NAME 
                  AND d1.stage = 1 AND d3.stage = 3
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/406b6/3)